# jQuery: .validate() function and Submit Once Function

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet of code to Submit a form once, to prevent multiple database inserts:

```
        // Validates the form data
        // Running before submit, otherwise HTTP process starts and we POST
        $(".empForm").validate();
        // Setting the submit button to enabled
        $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", false);
        // disabling the submit button after it's been pressed atleast once
        // Prevents duplicate entries in the database
        $(".empForm").submit(function(){
            // if it's valid, lock the submit button 
            // if the form is not valid, they can complete and try again
            if($(".empForm").valid()){
              $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true).val("Please wait...");
              return true;
            }// closes if
        }); //closes submit
```

The problem is I use the .validate() function of jQuery and when the form comes back as missing fields, I cannot submit the form because it's disabled. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one.

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
    if($(".empForm").valid()==true){
     $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true).val("Please wait...");}
      else{$("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", false);}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery/Validate submit handler that's provided.

```
$(".selector").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
   $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true).val("Please wait...");
   form.submit();
 }
})
```

SubmitHandler only runs if the form is valid, so this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling it, turn it Readonly

[Example](http://jetlogs.org/2007/12/16/jquery-disabled-and-readonly-inputs/)

```
('#readonly').click( 
function() 
{ 
    if ($('#readonly').attr("readonly") == true) 
    { 
        $('#readonly').val(''); 
        $('#readonly').removeAttr("readonly"); 
    } 
});
```

For your particular case : (Not tested)

```
$("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("readonly"); 
//or  $("input[type='submit']").attr('readonly', false) 
// disabling the submit button after it's been pressed atleast once
        // Prevents duplicate entries
        $("form").submit(function(){
          $("input[type='submit']").attr('readonly', true).val("Please wait...");
          return true;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks man. Can you look at my edited code and see if that's do able instead?